# Extract List of ORACLE errors from a tomcat log

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat

Looking for some quick help (hopefully); I am looking for a way to extract ORACLE errors from a tomcat log; for example

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/07/30 00:00:29.038 | Exception in thread "TaskExecutor-master-3734-ProcessTask [8799338038198]" com.business.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DATABASE.DATABASE_IDX_3) violated
```

And what I would like to do is create a distinct list of Oracle errors as its output

Output Example:

```
ORA-00001
ORA-00932
ORA-00000
```

Anyone have a handy script out there?  Thanks, for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP ' \KORA-[0-9]{5}(?=:)' file
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Just added grep -oP ' \KORA-[0-9]{5}(?=:)' file | sort | uniq to make it unique... :)

Comment: Feel free to replace `sort | uniq` by `sort -u` if you have access to GNU sort.